# GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP min/mag filter problem

Tags: cubemap

I found it hard getting min/mag filtering to work with cubemap texture. In the screenshot-attachment I've created a cube using a cubemap texture, and also a grid of planes using a 2D texture. For both the cubemap and 2D texture I use GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, for min-filter. For 2D texture it works, but for the cubemap it doesn't.

[image]

Below, I've listed the code for how I set up my cubemap texture. I would be glad if someone could help me out with this, thanks in advance :)

```
levels = floor(log2(max(width, height))) + 1;


glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);
glGenTextures(1, &id);
glActiveTexture(textureUnit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, id);


glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, levels, internalFormat, width, height);


for (GLenum target = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, i = 0; target <= GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z; target++, i++)
{
    glTexSubImage2D(target, 0, 0, 0, width, height, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,    cubeMapList[i]->pixels);
}


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. The top face of the cube, which is screen-space narrow similarly to the far end of the plane, appears similarly filtered.

Comment: Aha okay, I see. Then how come there is only filtering in the xz-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's working normally to me. The top face of the cube, which is screen-space narrow similarly to the far end of the plane, appears similarly filtered.

The other faces of the cube do not display any blurriness because they are wide enough in both dimensions to not require minification. Remember, mipmapping isn't *intended* to make distant textures blurry. It's intended to blur (rather, low-pass-filter) distant textures *as required to avoid aliasing*.

If you want everything to be *consistently* blurry at distance, then what you want is a *depth-of-field* effect, which is considerably more complex to implement.

If you don't specifically want blurring but just want surfaces to be more consistent with each other, try using *anisotropic filtering*, which eliminates the effect of surfaces which have different scales in the two texture axes (like the top of the cube or the plane) getting blurred along both axes equally. It's mipmapping extended to operate independently in both axes.

Comment: Very good explanation, it feels so obvious now, thanks a lot! :)